# unrecognized selector sent to instance in ViewController using Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, unrecognized-selector

I've been looking around for a fix, but couldn't seem to fix it by myself.

I'm trying to sent notifications through my controller - model. I'm getting an error on my appdelegate saying:

> [Test.ViewController naamInModelChangedHandler]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x7f81c85006c0

I'm sending my notification in my viewDidLoad like this:

```
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: "naamInModelChangedHandler",
        name: "NAAM_CHANGED",
        object: model)
```

In my ViewController I made a function like this:

```
    func naamInModelChangedHandler ( notification:NSNotification ) {
    println("De naam in de model is veranderd naar \(model.naam!)")
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(
                self,
                name: "NAAM_CHANGED",
                object: model)
}
```

And this is how my model looks like (but I don't think this has anything to do with it? :

```
var naam: String? {
didSet {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NAAM_CHANGED", object: self)
}
```

Anyone who could help me out fixing this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the selector should be `"naamInModelChangedHandler:"`. Note the `:` since `naamInModelChangedHandler` takes an `NSNotification` as an argument. Therefore, you should add the observer like so:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: "naamInModelChangedHandler:",
        name: "NAAM_CHANGED",
        object: model)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I not yet have 15 reputation, so I can't upvote. This worked. Seems like I missed that small thing.

Comment: Glad that solved your problem :) You can't upvote, but you can mark an answer as correct (the tick on the left hand side). @Ckouta answered just before me so you should mark his as correct.